# Set default value of job param dynamically in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to set the default value of a choice parameter dynamically to TRUE or FALSE through pipeline script with an input(TRUE/FALSE of that parameter itself)

So that in the next execution no need to set the default value again it should take the value from the previous execution until there is a change in choice once again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, Check the sample below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { booleanParam(name: 'FLAG', defaultValue: FLAG, description: '') }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Build"
                        
                    }
                   
               }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: it seems default value is fixed. Is there a possible way to set it dynamically??

Comment: @dev it's not fixed. What ever value you select as the Parameter (true or false) will be set as the default value.

Comment: as per the snippet here param name is not 'FLAG' it is  a value. Any how we are passing  a default value without any condition. I have different param name whose default value has to be set but not default value itself.